# Perforce api - How to Command "Get Latest Revision"

Tags: c#, api, perforce, p4api.net

I use Perforce Api (.net c#) works.

source...

```
//--------Connect--------
Perforce.P4.Server server = new Perforce.P4.Server(new Perforce.P4.ServerAddress("111.222.333.444"));
        Perforce.P4.Repository rep = new Perforce.P4.Repository(server);
        Perforce.P4.Connection con = rep.Connection;

        con.UserName = "PSY";
        string password = "gangnamstyle";
        con.Client = new Perforce.P4.Client();

        Perforce.P4.Options opconnect = new Perforce.P4.Options();
        opconnect.Add("-p", password);

        con.Connect(opconnect);
        con.Login(password);


//--------How to ?--------
string ws_client = @"C:\ClientPath\";
string depot = "//depot/";

        Perforce.P4.P4Server p4Server = new Perforce.P4.P4Server(server.Address.Uri, con.UserName, password, ws_client);
        Perforce.P4.P4Command com = new Perforce.P4.P4Command(p4Server);



//--------Disconnect---------
con.Disconnect();
```

Perforce commands of this  "Get Latest Revision"

Comment: Does the workspace in `c:\ClientPath` already exist, or do you also need to create it?

Comment: "c:\ClientPath" is workwpace.  This path has created.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the workspace for `c:\clientPath` setup on your machine and assuming it has the name `myWorkspace` (as in the "Workspace" column in the "Workspaces" tab in p4v), then:

```
client.Name = "myWorkspace";
client.Initialize(con);
con.Client = client; // otherwise later things fail somewhat mysteriously
con.CommandTimeout = new TimeSpan(0); // otherwise the sync is likely to time out

client.SyncFiles(new Perforce.P4.Options()); // sync everything
```

Comment: I have a question .
What do I do if I want to set the sub-path ?

Comment: [client - c://ClientPath/CurrentDirectory/]
[depot - //depot/CurrentDirectory/]

*How to synchronize all files under the path CurrentDirectory

Comment: `SyncFiles` takes a second argument that allows you to specify the path(s) to sync. If you can't figure out how to use it ask a separate question as the details won't fit into a comment well (there's a couple of calls needed in a chain to setup the `FileSpec` type)